# Changing videocam resolution on Skype?

Tags: windows-7, windows, skype

Windows 7, Skype 7.40
CPU is i5, 16 gigs of RAM and Nvidia 1070 video card. 
Monitors all display 1920 resolution.

My webcam supports 1600x1200  but I can't figure out how to set the webcam to this resolution.

I tried looking at the config.xml file for

`<TransferWindow>`

as suggested in this thread, but couldn't find that key:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1482953

(Note above link is ubuntu, but my question is Windows related)

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @Ramhoud Hi, I'm only asking one question: How to change the videocam resolution on Skype. Is there some sort of confusion in my OP?  Thank you.

Comment: You linked to an article which only applies to the Linux version of Skype, but you are using the Windows version of Skype, so your question isn't clear.  You also didn't supply any hardware specifications.  Skype should be using the highest resolution your camera supports automatically, there isn't a specific way, to increase the resolution of your camera in Skype on Windows

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry about that. The ubuntu thread was the best info I could find as to how to change resolutions. Ah, if that's the case, I guess I need to play around with other settings to improve image quality. I will update my OP.